# Why do my coefficients become unbelievably large when I include an interaction term in glm? (R)

Tags: r, glm

Thank you ahead of time, I am somewhat new to R. I am running a model that is trying to find the relationship between policies and public opinion. I am trying to predict whether a state has a policy or not based on public opinion and other factors. However, I find that when I try to include an interaction term between two of my predictors, the coefficients and z-values become unbelievably large and my p-values close to 1. However, when I use robust standard errors, the p-values get incredibly small but my coefficients remain extremely large. I have no idea what the statistical reasoning behind this could be. What is the reason why my model changes so drastically when I include the interaction term?

Here is the difference between the regressions:

```
employ.interact.pol<-glm(employpolicy~ predicted_support$support_job_protections
                              + govapprove_employ
                              + court.elected 
                              + professional.index + professional.index * court.elected
                              + pdemocrat + pdemocrat * predicted_support$support_job_protections
                              + p.evang + p.evang * predicted_support$support_job_protections
                              + inquirepermil_employ
                              + anti_gay_group_splc + anti_gay_group_splc * predicted_support$support_job_protections,
                         family = binomial(link = "logit"),
                         data=statecodes)
summary(employ.interact.pol)
vcvpolicy_employ<-vcovHC(employ.interact.pol,type = "HC1")
coeftest(employ.interact.pol,vcvpolicy_employ)

employ.interact.pol2<-glm(employpolicy~ predicted_support$support_job_protections
                         + govapprove_employ
                         + court.elected 
                         + professional.index + professional.index * court.elected
                         + pdemocrat + pdemocrat * predicted_support$support_job_protections
                         + p.evang + p.evang * predicted_support$support_job_protections
                         + inquirepermil_employ
                         + anti_gay_group_splc + anti_gay_group_splc * predicted_support$support_job_protections
                         + govapprove_employ * predicted_support$support_job_protections,
                         family = binomial(link = "logit"),
                         data=statecodes)
summary(employ.interact.pol2)
vcvpolicy_employ<-vcovHC(employ.interact.pol2,type = "HC1")
coeftest(employ.interact.pol2,vcvpolicy_employ)
```

Here is the output for the first regression, with and without robust SEs:

```
summary(employ.interact.pol)

Call:
glm(formula = employpolicy ~ predicted_support$support_job_protections + 
    govapprove_employ + court.elected + professional.index + 
    professional.index * court.elected + pdemocrat + pdemocrat * 
    predicted_support$support_job_protections + p.evang + p.evang * 
    predicted_support$support_job_protections + inquirepermil_employ + 
    anti_gay_group_splc + anti_gay_group_splc * predicted_support$support_job_protections, 
    family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = statecodes)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-2.31714  -0.03843   0.00055   0.20780   1.45159  

Coefficients:
                                                               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)                                                    51.15444  103.19674   0.496   0.6201  
predicted_support$support_job_protections                     -72.53352  135.06644  -0.537   0.5913  
govapprove_employ                                               4.94161    2.74864   1.798   0.0722 .
court.elected                                                   4.18208    5.19325   0.805   0.4207  
professional.index                                              0.23568   25.92217   0.009   0.9927  
pdemocrat                                                      -0.63226    1.60790  -0.393   0.6942  
p.evang                                                        -5.21383    3.47383  -1.501   0.1334  
inquirepermil_employ                                            0.06558    0.03175   2.066   0.0389 *
anti_gay_group_splc                                           -39.77388   40.68583  -0.978   0.3283  
court.elected:professional.index                              -22.56114   31.26070  -0.722   0.4705  
predicted_support$support_job_protections:pdemocrat             0.95835    2.19436   0.437   0.6623  
predicted_support$support_job_protections:p.evang               6.01728    4.37460   1.376   0.1690  
predicted_support$support_job_protections:anti_gay_group_splc  53.81932   54.24065   0.992   0.3211  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 67.745  on 48  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 19.730  on 36  degrees of freedom
  (1 observation deleted due to missingness)
AIC: 45.73

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 10
```

And with robust SE:

```
vcvpolicy_employ<-vcovHC(employ.interact.pol,type = "HC1")
> coeftest(employ.interact.pol,vcvpolicy_employ)

z test of coefficients:

                                                                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)                                                    51.154437  72.548465  0.7051  0.48074  
predicted_support$support_job_protections                     -72.533520  95.772761 -0.7574  0.44884  
govapprove_employ                                               4.941607   2.398239  2.0605  0.03935 *
court.elected                                                   4.182078   3.982931  1.0500  0.29372  
professional.index                                              0.235677  11.809199  0.0200  0.98408  
pdemocrat                                                      -0.632256   1.103909 -0.5727  0.56682  
p.evang                                                        -5.213829   2.663177 -1.9577  0.05026 .
inquirepermil_employ                                            0.065575   0.041048  1.5975  0.11015  
anti_gay_group_splc                                           -39.773884  42.157403 -0.9435  0.34544  
court.elected:professional.index                              -22.561141  17.938292 -1.2577  0.20850  
predicted_support$support_job_protections:pdemocrat             0.958353   1.490163  0.6431  0.52015  
predicted_support$support_job_protections:p.evang               6.017279   3.313198  1.8162  0.06935 .
predicted_support$support_job_protections:anti_gay_group_splc  53.819324  55.969504  0.9616  0.33626  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Here is the second regression with interaction:

```
summary(employ.interact.pol2)

Call:
glm(formula = employpolicy ~ predicted_support$support_job_protections + 
    govapprove_employ + court.elected + professional.index + 
    professional.index * court.elected + pdemocrat + pdemocrat * 
    predicted_support$support_job_protections + p.evang + p.evang * 
    predicted_support$support_job_protections + inquirepermil_employ + 
    anti_gay_group_splc + anti_gay_group_splc * predicted_support$support_job_protections + 
    govapprove_employ * predicted_support$support_job_protections, 
    family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = statecodes)

Deviance Residuals: 
       Min          1Q      Median          3Q         Max  
-1.851e-04  -2.100e-08   2.100e-08   2.100e-08   1.638e-04  

Coefficients:
                                                                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)                                                    6.147e+03  7.150e+06   0.001    0.999
predicted_support$support_job_protections                     -8.990e+03  9.100e+06  -0.001    0.999
govapprove_employ                                             -5.794e+03  2.418e+06  -0.002    0.998
court.elected                                                  4.478e+02  2.545e+05   0.002    0.999
professional.index                                             1.116e+03  1.618e+06   0.001    0.999
pdemocrat                                                     -3.388e+01  1.204e+05   0.000    1.000
p.evang                                                       -4.392e+02  8.039e+04  -0.005    0.996
inquirepermil_employ                                           9.712e-01  1.070e+03   0.001    0.999
anti_gay_group_splc                                            6.750e+02  7.651e+05   0.001    0.999
court.elected:professional.index                              -2.408e+03  1.326e+06  -0.002    0.999
predicted_support$support_job_protections:pdemocrat            5.990e+01  1.614e+05   0.000    1.000
predicted_support$support_job_protections:p.evang              5.474e+02  1.070e+05   0.005    0.996
predicted_support$support_job_protections:anti_gay_group_splc -6.256e+02  1.156e+06  -0.001    1.000
predicted_support$support_job_protections:govapprove_employ    7.842e+03  3.300e+06   0.002    0.998

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 6.7745e+01  on 48  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 1.2319e-07  on 35  degrees of freedom
  (1 observation deleted due to missingness)
AIC: 28
```

And with robust SE:

```
vcvpolicy_employ<-vcovHC(employ.interact.pol2,type = "HC1")
> coeftest(employ.interact.pol2,vcvpolicy_employ)

z test of coefficients:

                                                                 Estimate  Std. Error z value  Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                                                    6.1470e+03  2.1610e+02  28.445 < 2.2e-16 ***
predicted_support$support_job_protections                     -8.9898e+03  3.0238e+02 -29.730 < 2.2e-16 ***
govapprove_employ                                             -5.7937e+03  1.3892e+02 -41.706 < 2.2e-16 ***
court.elected                                                  4.4779e+02  1.3052e+01  34.308 < 2.2e-16 ***
professional.index                                             1.1164e+03  2.3663e+01  47.178 < 2.2e-16 ***
pdemocrat                                                     -3.3876e+01  2.2151e+00 -15.294 < 2.2e-16 ***
p.evang                                                       -4.3919e+02  1.2361e+01 -35.532 < 2.2e-16 ***
inquirepermil_employ                                           9.7118e-01  6.0598e-02  16.027 < 2.2e-16 ***
anti_gay_group_splc                                            6.7501e+02  3.2781e+01  20.591 < 2.2e-16 ***
court.elected:professional.index                              -2.4079e+03  6.7000e+01 -35.938 < 2.2e-16 ***
predicted_support$support_job_protections:pdemocrat            5.9899e+01  3.2606e+00  18.371 < 2.2e-16 ***
predicted_support$support_job_protections:p.evang              5.4741e+02  1.5567e+01  35.166 < 2.2e-16 ***
predicted_support$support_job_protections:anti_gay_group_splc -6.2556e+02  4.2006e+01 -14.892 < 2.2e-16 ***
predicted_support$support_job_protections:govapprove_employ    7.8421e+03  1.8746e+02  41.835 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Thank you again for any explanations you can offer, I truly appreciate it!

Comment: Did you get any warning? Something in the lines of "did not converge" or "singular matrix"?

Comment: Curiously, no. It just gives me the output with no warnings.

Comment: It is quite strange that suddenly all coefficients become huge by adding one additional interaction term. Large coefficients are normally due to: outliers/un-scaled variables/highly skewed variables/rare events. Given the sudden collapse on all variable, the problem probably lies in the large number of interaction terms created and their correlation (collinearity). Try computing the covariance matrix and inspect it visually.

Comment: Thank you so much, this explains it! I had to omit one of the variables due to a large amount of multicollinearity.